# Chrome Devtools extension add network panel sidebar

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is is possible to add a new sidebar to the network panel in Chrome devtools?

I have checked the chrome devtools API documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels) but there only seems to be mention of the elements and sources panels.

Just wondering if maybe someone knows if it is possible to gain access to the other panels?

My goal is to add a new tab after the timing tab that can show some relevant information about this specific request and its contents.

[image: Screenshot_1]

Comment: No, only element picker can have a sidebar, see the [documentation for createSidebarPane](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-ElementsPanel).

Comment: BTW the documentation is auto-generated from the [source JSON](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/devtools/panels.json) that defines the API.

Comment: Ok, I had figured this was the case. Just thought I would ask anyway, thanks for the source JSON, that is very useful. Cheers!

Comment: FYI, as of 2022 (perhaps earlier) you can also add sidebar panes to the Sources panel, see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/devtools_panels/#type-SourcesPanel